# Click sub-links in a div?

Tags: javascript

I want to click 4 different links within a div that have no ID.
Let's say the div's name is "links".

So I want it to click link #1 of 5 inside of this div.

I would prefer to use `location.href`.

How can this be done?

Comment: Is this straight Javascript or can you use jQuery? And can you post some code to go with your question?

Comment: And you can't provide an example? Is this homework?

Comment: so your div have no id but have a name? OMG.

Comment: @aSeptik: I think he means the div has an ID of 'links' and the links within it have no ID.

Comment: @Town: ok, and what about "I want to click 4 different links" ... "click link #1 of 5 inside" double OMG

Comment: @aSeptik: I'm out of explanations...

Answer (score 0):

You can use some jQuery to trigger a `click` event on the first `a` element inside a `div`, given that the div's ID is `links` as you said:

```
$('div#links a:first').click();
```

Comment: That'd click the first link in *every* div though... I think more context is required from the OP before this question can be properly answered.

Comment: @Town - Not quite. It's `div#links`, which would be a subset of all div's. Not saying it's great, but your comment isn't exactly accurate.

Comment: In hansengels example, it uses an ID, so only that div would be found by the query.

Comment: @Jared: The original text of hansengel's post was `div a:first`, so my comment *was* exactly accurate, it just isn't anymore ;)

Comment: I edited my answer after Town's comment. He was correct, I left out an ID in the original, so it would've selected all the `div`s.

Comment: @Town - I have one `r` in my first name.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean... ;D

Comment: @Town - hansengel gives you credit, so my apologies. I can only judge what I see, if there are no edits logged on the question.

Comment: @Town - I have one `r` in my first name? Is that difficult to decipher?

Comment: @Town - I'm not going to play games with you - you know how I spell my name. ;)

Comment: @Jared: No offence taken and no apologies necessary (from you, at least!) Sorry, I couldn't resist continuing the edit-after-comment theme ;)

Comment: @Town - You're taking no offense? That's a novel defense.

Comment: @Town, I think he meant that the links have no ID - that's why he was asking for a special selector. Yeah, the question is a bit unclear :/

Comment: @Hansengel: Yes, you're right - I realised that after re-reading it (again).

Comment: Whatever. SO shouldn't be an exercise in quantum theory.

Answer (score 0):

> - **DEMO:** http://jsbin.com/ucedu5

```
//loop and assing onclick event to all <a> inside <div>
var div_a = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');     
  for (var i=0;i<div_a.length;i++) {
    div_a[i].onclick = function() {
    alert( this.href );
    };
  }
```

---

```
//loop and assing onclick event only to #1 <a> inside <div>
var div_a = document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a');   
  for (var i=0;i<div_a.length;i++) {
    if ( i === 0 ) {
    div_a[i].onclick = function() {
    alert( this.href );
    };
   }
  }
```

---

```
   //directly assing onclick event to the #1 <a> inside <div>
   document.getElementById('links').getElementsByTagName('a')[0].onclick = function(){
   alert( this.href );
   };
```